# Xml in Dot net 3.5:how to load xml document into object of class generated from schema?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xsd, xsd.exe

I have defined schema for xml in file "packetTemplate.xsd".Using ms tool "xsd.exe" i have  generated  class "PacketTemplate" corresponding to schema.Does dot net provides api that can load xml document by refering to file and returns object of class PacketTemplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some examples [here](http://sharpertutorials.com/serialization/).
A snippet:

```
  PacketTemplate myTemplate;

  XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PacketTemplate));
  FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("c:/mtTestClass.xml",FileMode.Open);

  myTemplate= (PacketTemplate)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

`Deserialize` has various [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx), you can also use an `XmlReader`.